# Silverstripe ignoring NULL filter in get command

Tags: php, silverstripe

We have a Silverstripe project that uses the following logic to find duplicate records:

```
if ($queryString) {
  $duplicate = SavedSearch::get()->filter(array(
    'RentOrBuy' => $rentOrBuy,
    'MemberID' => $member->ID,
    'QueryString' => $queryString, 
       ))->first();
} else {
  $duplicate = SavedSearch::get()->filter(array(
    'RentOrBuy' => $rentOrBuy,
    'MemberID' => $member->ID,
    'QueryString' => NULL, 
       ))->first();
}
```

However this doesn't return the expected responses. When $queryString is NULL it doesn't return any objects - even when QueryString is set as "NULL" on matching fields in the database.

Any ideas about why this is happening/ what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed for 4.0 from the looks
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/4196/commits/922d02f5356d5904debaf10003477cdd00306192

so for now..

```
if ($queryString) {
   $duplicate = SavedSearch::get()->filter(array(
    'RentOrBuy' => $rentOrBuy,
    'MemberID' => $member->ID,
    'QueryString' => $queryString, 
   ))
  ->first();
} else {
   $duplicate = SavedSearch::get()->filter(array(
     'RentOrBuy' => $rentOrBuy,
    'MemberID' => $member->ID
   ))
   ->where('QueryString IS NULL')
  ->first();
}
```

Be careful when using `where`, since it wont do any sql escaping. Here its fine but always use the `filter` when passing in user data.